# Unity не видит внешнюю библиотеку?

Tags: unity3d, dll

Ситуация такова: решил сделать небольшой проект по работе с bluetooth на c#. Использую для этого стороннюю библиотеку 32feet.NET - скачал установил, в студии через Проект - добавить ссылку - подключил dll файл библиотеки, прописал нужные мне using - все в порядке - все классы и типы появились, студия все спокойно видит, никаких ошибок не выдает.
Но Unity3d в которой я и делаю этот проект (под android разрабатывать пока что не умею, а тут и ui и все что нужно и под практически любую ос можно собрать) - упорно не видит классы и типы данных использованные в проекте, хотя библиотека подключена.

UPD: при сборке проекта в студии - типы тоже не видны, но я же подключил dll библиотеку?

Comment: Т.к. юнити использует свой собственный компилятор, то, что вы добавили `dll` в проект visual studio ничего вам не дает. Посмотрите ссылку https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UsingDLL.html. Если же нужно использовать `unmanaged dll`, то нужно закинуть ее в папку `Plugins`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, чтобы использовать [managed dll](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UsingDLL.html) в своем проекте, вам нужно лишь добавить ее в папку проекта *unity* (`Assets` или дочернюю).

Делается это именно так, а не через *solution* в студии по причине того, что *unity* использует свой собственный компилятор, поэтому и определяет все плагины собственными методами.

В случае, если вы хотите использовать [native dll](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/NativePlugins.html) (к примеру, написанную на c++), то ее нужно подключать так, как описано по ссылочке, + закинуть в папку [Plugins](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpecialFolders.html).